# moderncv.cls, how to use variables like email

Tags: moderncv

Maybe I am missing out something very simple but I cannot access variables from the moderncv class. For example if I assign the variable email with `\email{testmail@test.com}` I cannot call it by `\@email` inside the document, though it is defined by `\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}` in the moderncv.cls file. However, if I issue `\renewcommand{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}` I get the desired result.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       

\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%\renewcommand{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}} % Activate to make email variable work

\name{John}{Doe}            
\email{testmail@test.com}
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
Email is: \@email

\end{document}
```

Result without renewcommand:

[image]

Result with renewcommand:

[image]

Comment: `\makeatletter\@email\makeatother` -- it's a hidden command, that's why you need `\makeatletter...\makeatother`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Thanks a lot. That indeed was the issue. If you post it as answer I would gladly accept it. [Optional: Could you give a hint, how to identify a hidden variable? I mean just by looking at the class code.]

Comment: Done already ;-)

Comment: Actually any command that has an `@` - letter in it is considered to be hidden from normal usage, i.e. by a document writer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\@email` is a hidden command (or should be hidden, since it starts with `\@`. In order to access such `\@....` commands you need a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair.)

In a `.sty` or `.cls` file there should be no `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pairs, the `\@....` etc. commands are directly accessible there!

Best wrap this pair around an accessing macro, say `\retrieveemail` and don't use `\@email` directly.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       

\moderncvstyle{casual}                            
\moderncvcolor{blue}                             

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

%\renewcommand{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}} % Activate to make email variable work

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\retrieveemail}{\@email}
\makeatother

\name{John}{Doe}            
\email{testmail@test.com}
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

Email is: \retrieveemail

\end{document}
```

Comment: how would this work for a variable like `phone` which has options line `mobile` etc